# Trigger on update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored proc which has complicated logic. Upon completion of which I want to run another logic to calculate something. But the second logic is independent and I want to return back the control to user once the stored proc is complete. What is the best way to do this?

Right now, I am using a log table and have created a trigger on update of a column "end_time". But this does not release the thread execution.

Let me know if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update triggers are synchronous and run un the context of the UPDATE transaction. If you need to run an asynchronous process using T-SQL alone, consider Service Broker. Be aware there's a bit of a learning curve if you haven't used SB before.

Comment: What other option I have? I can think of creating a SQLAgent job which might run every 2 mins and keep checking for the ending of the stored proc run.

Comment: Sure, you could also poll using a SQL Agent job or similar.